# In how many ways can a test be passed with just $10$ right answers if at least $4$ right answers must be from part A of the test?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A test consists of two parts with a total of $24$ questions. Part A contains $8$ questions and part B contains $16$ questions. In order to pass the test, a total of $10$ questions are required, of which at least $4$ are correct on part A.
In how many different ways can you get just $10$ right answers and pass the test?

Answer (score 1):

${8\choose4}\cdot {16\choose6}+{8\choose5}\cdot {16\choose5}+{8\choose6}\cdot {16\choose4}+{8\choose7}\cdot {16\choose3}+{8\choose8}\cdot {16\choose2}=860728$

I am sure you can easily read from my formula how I reasoned. If not, just ask in the comments.

Comment: I understand your solution, but is it possible to solve it in any other way than that. For example,  If you take C(24,10) and then subtract C(16,7), C(16,8), C(16,9) and C(16,10) from it. I tried it but I got wrong answer. What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: The problem is that using C(24,10) you don't specify how many questions there are in part A and substracting the other combinations doesn't either, so you must reason using the amount of questions in part A to get a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given the nature of the question I'm assuming that you know that given a set of $n$ elements, there are exactly $n \choose k$ ways to choose $k$ elements from this set (where order doesn't matter), where $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $0 \leq k \leq n$ and ${n \choose k }= \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.

Now, suppose that we get exactly $k$ correct on Part A. The requirement is that $k \geq 4$, and since we wish to have exactly 10 right but Part A has only 8 questions we find that $k \leq 8$. Consequently, we need to have $10 - k$ correct on Part B.

Using the first paragraph, we we choose exactly $8 \choose k$ questions from Part A, and $16 \choose k$ questions from part B. If we now sum over all possible $k$, we obtain the result:
$$ \sum_{k=4}^{8} {8 \choose k} \cdot {16 \choose 10 - k}.$$
Although this is possibly not the most elegant form, it is not a hard calculation, and the [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(8+choose+k)+*+(16+choose+(10-+k))+for+k+%3D+4+to+8) is $860728$.